# Is there a `jq` command line tool or wrapper which lets you interactively explore `jq` similar to `jmespath.terminal`

Tags: json, wrapper, interactive, jq

`jq` is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Is there a `jq` command line tool or wrapper which lets you pipe output into it and interactively explore `jq`, with the JSON input in one pane and your interactively updating result in another pane, similar to `jmespath.terminal` ?

I'm looking for something similar to the JMESPath Terminal `jpterm`
"JMESPath exploration tool in the terminal"
https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.terminal

I found this project `jqsh` but it's not maintained and it appears to produce a lot of errors when I use it.
https://github.com/bmatsuo/jqsh

I've used https://jqplay.org/ and it's a great web based `jq` learning tool. However, I want to be able to, in the shell, pipe the json output of a command into an interactive `jq` which allows me to explore and experiment with `jq` commands.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've been using `jiq` and I'm pretty happy with it.

https://github.com/fiatjaf/jiq

It's [jid](https://github.com/simeji/jid) with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

You can drill down interactively by using jq filtering queries.

`jiq` uses `jq` internally, and it requires you to have `jq` in your PATH.

**Using the `aws` cli**

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --region-names us-east-1 us-west-1 | jiq
```

**`jiq` output**

```
[Filter]> .Regions
{
  "Regions": [
    {
      "Endpoint": "ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      "RegionName": "us-east-1"
    },
    {
      "Endpoint": "ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com",
      "RegionName": "us-west-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/simeji/jid

n.b. I'm not clear how strictly it follows jq syntax and feature set

Answer (score 1):

You may have to roll-your-own.

Of course, jq itself is interactive in the sense that if you invoke it without specifying any JSON input, it will process STDIN interactively.

If you want to feed the same data to multiple programs, you could easily write your own wrapper. Over at github, there's [a bash script named jqplay](https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/b9d4085703944114e72fbe4afcd7d0d1) that has a few bells and whistles.  For example, if the input command begins with | then the most recent result is used as input.

#### Example 1

```
./jqplay -c spark.json
Enter a jq filter (possibly beginning with "|"), or blank line to terminate:
.[0]
{"name":"Paddington","lovesPandas":null,"knows":{"friends":["holden","Sparky"]}}
.[1]
{"name":"Holden"}
| .name
"Holden"
| .[0:1]
"H"
| length
1
.[1].name
"Holden"

Bye.
```

#### Example 2

```
./jqplay -n
Enter a jq filter (possibly beginning and/or ending with "|"), or blank line to terminate:
?
An initial | signifies the filter should be applied to the previous jq
output.

A terminating | causes the next line that does not trigger a special
action to be appended to the current line.

Special action triggers:
:exit        # exit this script, also triggered by a blank line
:help        # print this help
:input PATHNAME ...
:options OPTIONS
:save PN     # save the most recent output in the named file provided
               it does not exist
:save! PN    # save the most recent output in the named file 
:save        # save to the file most recently specified by a :save command
:show        # print the OPTIONS and PATHNAMEs currently in effect
:! PN        # equivalent to the sequence of commands
               :save! PN 
               :input PN
?            # print this help
#            # ignore this line

1+2
3
:exit
Bye.
```

Comment: Thanks for coming up with these options! For some reason when I try to use the `jqplay` script I get `jq: 1 compile error` errors and I haven't looked into it yet. I ended up discovering `jiq` in a Hacker News thread and it does pretty much what I want for now.

Comment: @caleban - jiq was forked from https://github.com/simeji/jid so I'm wondering if you know anything about the relative merits of the two. Regarding the bash script -- it has been tested with two different versions of GNU bash (v3 and v4), so I suspect the errors you're seeing are simply jq finding some kind of mismatch between your query and the input you're giving it.  For help on jqplay: jqplay -h

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Emacs (or willing to) then JQ-mode allows you to run JQ filters interactively on the current JSON document buffer:

https://github.com/ljos/jq-mode

Answer (score 1):

There is a new one: https://github.com/PaulJuliusMartinez/jless

> JLess is a command-line JSON viewer designed for reading, exploring, and searching through JSON data.
>
> JLess will pretty print your JSON and apply syntax highlighting.
>
> Expand and collapse Objects and Arrays to grasp the high- and low-level structure of a JSON document. JLess has a large suite of vim-inspired commands that make exploring data a breeze.
>
> JLess supports full text regular-expression based search. Quickly find the data you're looking for in long String values, or jump between values for the same Object key.